# Why my ViewBinder shows the last element wrong?

Tags: android

I have a big problem and I tried to debug it for a long time but I can not get the error.

I have a Listview and load it with pictures, where the Path is saved in the database.

**Its all works fine, but I have one Problem:** 
If I have e.g. 4 items. The first two have pictures and the last 2 not. So the last item in the list always have the picture from the last item which had a picture and I can not figure out why. I looked in the database if it maybe have a Path in it for the last element but its empty.

There is my code:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.my_listlayout, 
        MainController.getInstance().getMyCursor(db), 
        new String[] {"F1", "F2", "F3", "F4"}, 
        new int[] {R.id.imageViewF1, R.id.textViewF2, R.id.textViewF3, R.id.textViewF4}, 0);

adapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder() {
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex == 1) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;

            String Pic = cursor.getString(1);

            if (Pic != null) {
                // load the picture in the view
                imageView.setImageDrawable(...);
            }
            return true;
        }
        if (columnIndex == 2) {
            //..
        }
        if (columnIndex == 3) {
            //..
        }
        if (columnIndex == 4) {
            //..
        }

        return false;
    }
});


ListView view = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewFirst);
view.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Maybe I'M doing something wrong in the adapter?

Comment: I am not familiar with ViewBinder, but the columnIndex starts with 0 i think

Comment: but the other pictures except the last item which is loading are right

Comment: Did you try it out to add an **else** in case that the **Pic != null**? try something like this: `(...) if(Pic != null) { imageView.setImageDrawable(...); } else { imageView.setVisibility(view.GONE) } (...)` I think that this can be a solution.